How do I properly import dynamic component strapi in Nuxt 3?
I have two solutions. I would like to know which is the best, or if i do something wrong here?
Why resolveComponent Causes Blocking Rendering
Global imports: When you import components globally in your nuxt.config.js, they are included in the main bundle. This increases the size of the initial JavaScript bundle that needs to be downloaded and parsed before the page can become interactive.
Rendering Block: Larger bundles take longer to download, parse, and execute, causing a delay in rendering the page, which Lighthouse identifies as a blocking issue.
   <component
      v-if="isComponentExist(component)]"
      :is="strapiComponents(component)"
   />

   const isComponentExist = (component) => {
      const componentName = component.__component.split('.').pop();
      instance?.appContext.components[componentName(component)]
   }

    const strapiComponents = (component: string) => resolveComponent(componentName(component));

Optimizing the Second Solution with defineAsyncComponent
Dynamic Imports with Prefetching: Prefetch components to improve loading times. Suspense with Fallback: Use Suspense to handle loading states effectively.
    <head>
        <template v-for="component in props.config.components">
            <link rel="prefetch" :href="`../Strapi/${componentName(component)}.vue`" as="script" />
        </template>
    </head>
    <Suspense>
         <component
           :is="getComponent(component)"
          />
          <template #fallback>
             <UiLoading />
          </template>
     </Suspense>

    const getComponent = (component) => {
        const componentName = component.__component.split('.').pop();
        return defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`../Strapi/${componentName(component)}.vue`));
    };

I will expect the second solution to give me better performance. But thats does not look like to be the case. If i check the nuxt dev tools, it looks like all components are loaded.

I think that you need to either provide a static array of possible components or let Vite load the whole thing because it cannot determine which one to load on runtime because it's fully dynamic. Maybe something like this can help: https://www.lichter.io/articles/nuxt3-vue3-dynamic-images/#the-importmetaglob-trick

Thanks for the reply, I have updated my question to be more specific. You mean to go with the second solution defineAsyncComponent and rather than prefetch in the header to load components with the vite function import.meta.glob('../components/Strapi/*.vue');

Yeah what you have right now feels good. I could even advice to use Nuxt server components to remove any kind of hydration if you don't need it. Plus maybe generating all ahead of time. Not sure if you can or should explicitly use SSR.
